# Upload files - total size limit - Wordpress/Contact Form 7

Tags: database, uploads, plugin-contact-form-7

A client of mine wants visitors to be able to upload images that do not exceed 25mb in size combined... The thing is that it seems all contact form plugins that I checked can set file restrictions based on each file, not on the total files... Right now we are using contact form 7 but all the plugins I checked work in the same way. The client is not concerned about the file size though, he wants people to be able to upload 25mb in total... I've already increased the max file size upload to 25mb, but obviously this does not solve my issue.

Is there a way I can set it so visitors can upload up to 25mb files in total? Not 25mb each file, but total files uploaded... I tried the "Upload quota per user" plugin but it seems it's not working properly...

Any help is very much appreciated... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with the .user.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need a counter which will calculate the file size once they are uploaded... means for example.. if user uploaded 1st file of 5 MB and then rest other files are also 5 MB each then when he tries to upload 6th file of xyz MB then submit button gets disabled ... for achieving this you need to edit contact form 7 pluginn's core files...

Comment: This wouldn't survive a plugin update unfortunately so it is not an option...